# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {guid} failed due to the following error: XXXX Class not registered + Office 365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, office-365, word, autohosted

I am building SharePoint auto-hosted app. In that I have used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll. I have published app to the Office-365 environment. When my code reaches to the line where I am initializing the interop object it throws this error.

Line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

And Error I got :

```
Error in Default page: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
  at DocumentAppTestWeb.Pages.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

When I run my app by pressing F5 it runs perfectly.
But when I publish my .app file to the app catalog of my Office 365 environment it gives me above error.

Is there any option that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install  Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies on the machine you're deploying;

here is a link to Office 2010 in-case you're using Office 2010->
`http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508`